# Debian on Virtual Mips Malta platform

Tags: debian, debian-installer, mips, netboot

I am trying to run Debian on MipsMalta platform which is emulated by [OVP](http://www.ovpworld.org/).
The problem is that the setup tool needs to download files from Debian mirrors but it cannot proceed in downloading files, I tried many different mirrors from different countries, but I get the following message:

> The installer failed to download a file from the mirror. This maybe a
>   problem from your network, or with the mirror. You can choose to retry
>   to download, select a different mirror, or cancel and choose another
>   installation method.

I also changed the default Debian Installer embedded in OVP with the one available here: http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/installer-mipsel/current/images/malta/netboot/ but the same message appears.

Obviously, this method of installation is based on netboot. Do you know where exactly can I find the required files for offline method of installation, in case the netboot version is not fixed?

Comment: Welcome to Unix.stackexchange! I recommend you [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

I tried several other installers, it seems *wheezy* version is compatible with OVP. The Debian installers  inside the OVP are so old and the required files are not achievable in Debian server. I could run the Linux malta using files available in this address :

> http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy/main/installer-mipsel/20130613+deb7u3+b2/images/malta/netboot/

after downloading an replacing them with original files in OVP the installer could download from the server.
The scripts in the OVP need to read vmlinux file, so after downloading the installer the file vmlinux-3.2.0-4-4kc-malta should be renamed by vmlinux.